# Entity Framework core: Update an entity that is part of a many to many relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing a simple Notes-App in ASP.NET core + Entity Framework core and i have a problem with the **updating** of notes that are connected to many tags through a join table (NoteTags).

All properties of the note object are updated in the database (title,content,summary...) except for the entires in the join table NoteTags.

**Note** class:

```cs
public class Note
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        public List<NoteTag> NoteTags { get; set; } = new List<NoteTag>();
}
```

**Tag** class:

```cs
public class Tag
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int NotesCount { get; set; }

        public List<NoteTag> NoteTags { get; set; } = new List<NoteTag>();
}
```

Join-table **NoteTag**:

```cs
public class NoteTag
{
        public Note Note { get; set; }
        public int NoteId { get; set; }

        public Tag Tag { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }
}
```

The creating/deleting and updating of notes takes place in a repository class that manages the dbcontext.
The updating routine of the repository is called by the NotesController that handles a viewModel with the note to be edited.

**NotesController** => EditNote

```cs
 public IActionResult EditNote(EditNoteViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (viewModel.SelectedTags != null)
                {
                    var tagList = viewModel.SelectedTags.Split(" ");
                    foreach (string tagName in tagList)
                    {
                        if (tagName.Length != 0 && tagName != " ")
                        {
                            var tag = this._TagRepository.GetTagByName(tagName);

                            if (tag == null)
                                tag = this._TagRepository.CreateTag(new Tag { Name = tagName });

                            viewModel.NoteToEdit.NoteTags.Add(
                                new NoteTag { Note = viewModel.NoteToEdit, NoteId = viewModel.NoteToEdit.Id, Tag = tag, TagId = tag.Id }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }

                this._NoteRepository.EditNote(viewModel.NoteToEdit.Id, viewModel.NoteToEdit);
```

**Notes repository** => EditNote(..)

```cs
public void EditNote(int id,Note newNote)
        {
            var note = this.GetNote(id);
            foreach (var noteTag in newNote.NoteTags.ToList())
            {
                if (!note.NoteTags.Contains(noteTag))
                {
                    noteTag.Tag.NotesCount += 1;
                    note.NoteTags.Add(noteTag);
                }
            }

            foreach (var noteTag in note.NoteTags.ToList())
            {
                if (!newNote.NoteTags.Contains(noteTag))
                {
                    noteTag.Tag.NotesCount -= 1;
                    note.NoteTags.Remove(noteTag);
                }
            }

            note.Title = newNote.Title;
            note.Content = newNote.Content;
            note.CreationDateTime = newNote.CreationDateTime;
            note.Summary = newNote.Summary;

            this._context.Notes.Update(note);
            this._context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Lacks context. Show your view code.

Comment: I dont think its relevant because the problem occurs in the note repository class => the note title, note content etc are updated properly but the entries in the notetag join table arent updated in the way i except them to be updated

Comment: can you share ef core change tracking and command debug logs,  also have you configured many to many relationship in modelBuilder,  it needs to explicitly be able to map it successfully